# Which Event.target Property Should I Use?

Tags: javascript, naming-conventions

When finding which element an event originated from is there an event.target property that works best?

Take this block of code for example:

```
document.addEventListener("keypress", function (event) {

    if (event.target.className == "input-field")
        callFunctionName();

}, false);
```

This same piece of code works whether the `if` statement contains `event.target.nodeName == "INPUT"`, `event.target.dataset.field == "input"`, etc.

Is there any reason why one of these properties should be used over the others or maybe why one is worse than the rest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how specific you need to be. In particular, your current:

> `event.target.className == "input-field"`

is not particularly flexible - this will work only if the element has *that class*, `input-field`, and that class only. What if, later, you figure out that you want to add *another* class to that element, for styling or something? Then, the above test will fail, and you'll have to go back and fix it.

> This same piece of code works whether the if statement contains `event.target.nodeName == "INPUT"`

This will match *any* `input` field on the page, which may well be undesirable - what if additional HTML you add later happens to include an `<input>` that you don't want to trigger this handler? Then, you'll have to come back and fix this.

> `event.target.dataset.field == "input"`

This will result in the handler being triggered for *any* element with `data-field="input"`. While perhaps unlikely, what if such an element is added to the HTML later, one that you don't want this listener to be connected to? Then, again, you'll have to come back and fix it.

It's usually a good idea to be *as specific as possible* when targeting elements. You can do this with `Element.prototype.matches` - pass it a selector string (selector strings are very flexible), and it will return a boolean indicating whether the selector string matches the element:

```
if (event.target.matches('input.input-field[data-field="input"]')) {
  callFunctionName();
}
```

Comment: Really good points, seems like matches() makes the most sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No valid answer for that, depends of your case.

For example:

If you want to do only with one target, you will use ID.

If you want to do with inputs type text you will use `e.target.type`

If you want to do with inputs than can be selects or inputs but have the same class in common you will use className..

Think what you want and this will be the correct answer!

Answer (score 0):

### The most standard and reliable way to know what element triggered an event is with [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target).

What property(ies) you choose to access from that object really depends on what aspect of that object you are interested in.

[`nodeName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeName) always returns an all caps string containing the name of the HTML element (the tag name, not the element's `name` attribute or its `id`).

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("test1").nodeName); // SELECT
console.log(document.getElementById("test2").nodeName); // OPTION
console.log(document.getElementById("test3").nodeName); // OPTION
```

```html
<select id="test1">
  <option id="test2">Choice 1</option>
  <option id="test3">Choice 2</option>  
</select>
```

[`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) is used for a completely different reason. It returns a `data` attribute value for the [`data` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) specified after `.dataset`. The only way this API would be comparable to `event.target.nodeName` would be if you had an element similar to this:

```
<input type="text" data-field="input">
```

which is unlikely. Here's an example of how values of `data-*` attributes in your HTML elements can be retrieved in JavaScript.

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("test1").dataset.policyType); // Home
```

```html
<div id="test1" data-policy-type="Homeowners">Policy Number: 1234546</div>
```

The two APIs each serve their purpose, but they are not interchangeable.

Comment: Good lord guy, I'm already using event.target. Also, I know what the different properties do, I wasn't asking that. The question is with all these properties at our disposal which one is the most appropriate for determining the event origin.

Comment: @jjrabbit Did you not read the large, bold text at the top of my answer?! Or the second sentence? Good lord guy!

Comment: "event.target" that's your answer, okay.

Comment: @jjrabbit If your question is as you say: *which one is the most appropriate for determining the event origin*, then yes, `event.target` is the way to know which element triggered the event. And, as I said, after that, which property you use depends on what you are interested in - - there are dozens of different data points that any element may have.

Comment: @jjrabbit Given that you've been a member of this platform for a whopping 2 months, I'm sure you've read our guidelines on How to Ask a Question as well as our rules on civility. Clearly, you're question wasn't as "obvious" as you believe it was. And (for the third time), had you read through my answer and tried to understand it, you would have seen that I pointed out that there are many properties you can look at but it depends on what you are interested it, "obviously" informing you that there is no clear answer to the best property to look at. So, instead of berating, how about "thank you"?